# Define data type include constrained functions

Tags: haskell

I am trying to adopt the idea of [ReaderT pattern](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/readert-design-pattern) in a simple production system.

In the original example data type `Env` is defined as:

```
data Env = Env
  { envLog :: !(String -> IO ())
  , ...
  }
```

I my implementation, 
I defined a typeclass `Serializable` to help me logging different data types.
So that I could have a more generic logging function (including serialization in different file format):

```
data Env = Env
  { evnLog :: (Serializable a) => a -> FilePath -> IO ()
  , ...
  }
```

Of course, this doesn't work. The error message is:

```
    Not in scope: type variable ‘a’
   |
61 |   { envLog :: (Serializable a) =>
   |                             ^
```

If `a` is included in the Type constructor of `Env`, I will be forced to change the Context information in ReaderT constantly, it would be really cumbersome.

I just want to pass this generic function along a sequences of computations and use it whenever being needed.

Is there any possibility of not introducing  `a` in the Type constructor of `Env` ? Or maybe ReaderT pattern needs more tricks to be used like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to use a rank-2 type (specifically, the type of the `Env` data constructor). You need to both enable the `RankNTypes` extension, and use a `forall` since rank-2 types are never inferred:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data Env = Env
  { envLog :: forall a. (Serializable a) => a -> FilePath -> IO ()
  , ...
  }
```